# Enums shorthand calls - static imports

Tags: java, import, static-import

I am getting a little bit confused with import statements for enums. Consider following snippet:

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter getUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter() {

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter =
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter();
    usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.setAllowSessionCreation(false);
    usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.setUsernameParameter(SecurityConstants.CREDENTIALS_USERNAME.getText());
    usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.setPasswordParameter(SecurityConstants.CREDENTIALS_PASSWORD.getText());
```

This particular notation is too long:

```
SecurityConstants.CREDENTIALS_PASSWORD.getText()
```

to justify the usage of `enum` alltogether in this case. Is it possible to refer to enum like `CREDENTIALS_PASSWORD.getText()`?

I don't know why I have that feeling that it is possible, maybe JUnit assert statements static imports reflect in my brain as you can do short way `assertEquals()` with static imports.

Is there a way to do simillar with the enums?

Enum class itself:

```
public enum SecurityConstants {
    CREDENTIALS_PROCESSING_URL("app/authenticate"),
    CREDENTIALS_USERNAME("username"),
    CREDENTIALS_PASSWORD("password");

    private String text;

    SecurityConstants(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

```
import static SecurityConstants.*
```

JLS for the reference. 
[7.5.4. Static-Import-on-Demand Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.4)

> A static-import-on-demand declaration allows all accessible static members of a named type to be imported as needed.

```
StaticImportOnDemandDeclaration:
     import static TypeName . * ;
```

> The TypeName must be the canonical name (§6.7) of a class type, interface type, **enum** type, or annotation type.

Comment: You are the man! Thanks! 

import static com.company.configuration.security.SecurityConstants.*; solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

just import the enum, then you call the enum instance direct. Also you if you make the enum instance name, the same as the text you want - no need to call getText().

You have to use a static import btw.

Comment: /SecurityConfiguration.java:[97,67] cannot find symbol for normal import

Comment: and I can't use  'app/authenticate' as enum name too. This is why I find this myself tricky :-)

Comment: @Aubergine has to be static import

Comment: I figured out I was writing wrong static import after andrey showed how to do it. Thanks! I've update the tag accordingly so other people can find it.